# Can't disable systemd user timer, Unknown method DisableUnitFilesWithFlagsAndInstallInfo

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, d-bus, systemd-timer

I have a simple systemd service and timer under `~/.config/systemd/user` for building nightly images of my favorite program:

```
# ~/.config/systemd/user/kicad-build.service
[Unit]
Description=KiCAD nightly builder

[Service]
Type=simple
StandardOutput=null
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/jan/kicad-nightly-builder/build.sh
```

```
# ~/.config/systemd/user/kicad-build.timer
[Unit]
Description=KiCAD nightly build timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=daily
Persistent=true
RandomizedDelaySec=7200

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Now I wanted to disable the timer, as I don't need the nightly builds anymore:

```
[jan@memory-alpha user]$ systemctl --user stop kicad-build.timer

[jan@memory-alpha user]$ systemctl --user disable kicad-build.timer
Failed to disable unit: Unknown method DisableUnitFilesWithFlagsAndInstallInfo or interface org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager.
```

What is going on here? Why can `systemctl` not find the appropriate method for disabling the unit? The timer is still enabled:

```
[jan@memory-alpha user]$ systemctl --user status kicad-build.timer
○ kicad-build.timer - KiCAD nightly build timer
     Loaded: loaded (/home/jan/.config/systemd/user/kicad-build.timer; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2023-03-04 09:54:42 CET; 11min ago
   Duration: 1month 2w 5d 13h 3min 15.725s
    Trigger: n/a
   Triggers: ● kicad-build.service

Jan 13 10:21:26 memory-alpha systemd[901]: Started KiCAD nightly build timer.
Mar 04 09:54:42 memory-alpha systemd[901]: Stopped KiCAD nightly build timer.
```

Further testing:

```
[jan@memory-alpha user]$ gdbus introspect --system --dest org.freedesktop.systemd1 --object-path /org/freedesktop/systemd1 | grep DisableUnit
      DisableUnitFiles(in  as files,
      DisableUnitFilesWithFlags(in  as files,
      DisableUnitFilesWithFlagsAndInstallInfo(in  as files,

[jan@memory-alpha user]$ gdbus introspect --session --dest org.freedesktop.systemd1 --object-path /org/freedesktop/systemd1 | grep DisableUnit
      DisableUnitFiles(in  as files,
      DisableUnitFilesWithFlags(in  as files,
```

So apparently my system session has the appropriate method though my user session does not. Unfortunately I don't know enough about D-Bus to further debug this issue, any ideas?

```
[jan@memory-alpha user]$ uname -a
Linux memory-alpha 6.1.4-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat, 07 Jan 2023 15:10:07 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[jan@memory-alpha user]$ systemctl --version
systemd 253 (253-1-arch)
+PAM +AUDIT -SELINUX -APPARMOR -IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY +P11KIT -QRENCODE +TPM2 +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD +BPF_FRAMEWORK +XKBCOMMON +UTMP -SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified
```

Comment: I definitely don’t understand D-Bus but there is a similar issue here. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=283646. The solution seemed to be adding some config to ` "/usr/share/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.systemd1.conf"`. Hope this helps

Comment: Is your service enabled, by chance? I have (4) different user timers, all have a `Unit=` field, all services are disabled (only called by the timer itself). Running an Arch-based distro, user session systemd is working as expected (same version as yours). If troubleshooting doesn't work, then you may need to remove the timer manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system is running a systemd version which is too old compared to the version of systemctl. (This D-Bus method was added in systemd v253.)

Use `systemctl [--user] daemon-reexec` to upgrade the running systemd version.

Comment: You're right! I even tried `systemctl daemon-reexec` at some point but didn't know that you had to reload the user's systemd seperately. Thanks a lot!